# Wordpress category URL path changes

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I have a list of posts, each assigned to one or more categories.

When I am viewing the list of posts in Category1's page, the URL path is:

url.com/Category1

But I have a post that is classified under both Category 1 and Category 2. When I click on that post, the url path changes to url.com/Category2/postName

My question is how do I make it so that when I am viewing posts in Category1, the path will stay url.com/Category1/postName instead of changing to the other tagged categories.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [WordPress documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks):

```
   When you assign multiple categories to a post, only one can show up in the permalink. The categories are ordered alphabetically. In each group of sub-categories the order will also be alphabetical. (see Manage Categories). The post will still be accessible through all the categories as normal.
```

Therefore whenever you will assign multiple categories to a single post, WordPress will automatically choose one of those categories for creating the post URL (remember the categories are ordered alphabetically and the selection will be based accordingly).

You can avoid this by always assigning a single category to a post.